# You must be connected to the internet the first time you use the Grails wrapper

Tags: grails, circleci

I have a setup that used to work for at least a couple of years without any issues. In my latest update, all of a sudden I am getting the following error:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
./grailsw compile
You must be connected to the internet the first time you use the Grails wrapper
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 3; The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1473)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1749)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2967)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at grails.init.Start.getVersion(Start.java:36)
    at grails.init.Start.main(Start.java:83)

Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

And basically, I am getting the same error for any `grailsw` command.

Here is my config file:

```
version: 2.0
references:
  defaults: &defaults
    docker:
      - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk
    working_directory: ~/priz-be

  remote_docker: &remote_docker
    setup_remote_docker:
      docker_layer_caching: false

  assemble_prod: &assemble_prod
    run:
      name: Assemble
      command: ./gradlew -Dgrails.env=prod assemble

  build_and_push_docker_image: &build_and_push_docker_image
    run:
      name: Build docker image
      command: |
        sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
        sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev
        sudo pip install awscli
        cp -p build/libs/priz-be-0.1.war docker/app.war
        aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2 | sh
        docker build -t priz-be docker
        docker tag priz-be:latest 922556357703.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/priz-be:prod-$CIRCLE_SHA1
        docker push 922556357703.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/priz-be:prod-$CIRCLE_SHA1

jobs:
  checkout_code:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      - checkout

      - run:
          name: Show current branch
          command: echo ${CIRCLE_BRANCH}

      - save_cache:
          key: v1-repo-{{ .Environment.CIRCLE_SHA1 }}
          paths:
            - ~/priz-be

  compile:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-repo-{{ .Environment.CIRCLE_SHA1 }}
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}
            # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
            - v1-dependencies-
      - run:
          name: Compile the project
          command: ./grailsw compile

      # Cache local dependencies if they don't exist
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.gradle
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}

  test_and_check:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-repo-{{ .Environment.CIRCLE_SHA1 }}
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}
            # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
            - v1-dependencies-
      - run:
          name: Testing
          command: ./grailsw test-app

      - run:
          name: Executing stylecheck
          command: ./gradlew check

      - store_artifacts:
          path: ./build/reports/codenarc
          destination: codenarc-report

      - store_test_results:
          path: ./build/test-results/test

      - store_artifacts:
          path: ./build/reports/tests
          destination: test-report

  deploy_to_prod:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-repo-{{ .Environment.CIRCLE_SHA1 }}
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}
            # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
            - v1-dependencies-

      - *assemble_prod
      - *remote_docker
      - *build_and_push_docker_image

      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            - "9c:0c:ce:67:62:74:f1:d7:aa:b4:46:55:56:51:e5:f7"

      - run:
          name: Deploy
          command: |
            sudo apt-get update
            sudo apt-get -y install gettext-base
            sudo apt-get clean
            envsubst < docker/deploy-prod.sh.template > docker/deploy-prod.sh
            ssh -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@178.128.78.7 "bash -s" -- < ./docker/deploy-prod.sh

workflows:
  version: 2

  build-and-test:
    jobs:
      - checkout_code
      - compile:
          requires:
            - checkout_code
      - test_and_check:
          requires:
            - compile
      - deploy_to_prod:
          requires:
            - test_and_check
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master
```

If I log in with SSH, and trying to execute the same thing by hand, I am getting the same error. Also, checked if there is a network connection. All good...

What can be the reason for this error?

Comment: See https://github.com/grails/grails-wrapper/issues/7.

Comment: "You must be connected to the internet the first time you use the Grails wrapper" - btw... that has always been true, even before the recent outage.  The wrapper downloads Grails from the internet the first time it is run.

Answer (score 5):

This is caused by a problem with the Artifactory instance.  More information is available at [github.com/grails/grails-wrapper/issues/7](https://github.com/grails/grails-wrapper/issues/7) and [github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11825](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11825).

Comment: Oh wow! I see that there isn't really a workaround available for now. I am stuck :(

Comment: "Oh wow! I see that there isn't really a workaround available for now." - If the workaround described in that issue isn't working for you, that would be great information to share in the issue.  It appears to be working in all of the projects we have tested.  Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Yes get the updated `grails-wrapper.jar` for your grails version from the blog links as suggested in the discussion link

Answer (score -1):

The Grails Repository has been moved to an artifactory instance and the paths have changed.
You may have to update your maven repository url in build.gradle:

```
# Old repository url
maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }

# New url
maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/artifactory/core/" }
```

The only official information I found about this change was [Important Information Regarding Grails and Bintray](https://grails.org/blog/2021-02-12-alerts-regarding-bintray-sunset.html).

You can find all available repositories [here](https://repo.grails.org/ui/repos/tree/General/). (In case you need the [plugins repository](https://repo.grails.org/artifactory/plugins/) or anything else.)

I hope that fixes your problem.

Regards

Comment: The official information you linked there is unrelated to the problem posted in the question here.  https://github.com/grails/grails-wrapper/issues/7 and https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11825 are relevant though.

Comment: I don't think the change described here would fix the wrapper problem.  Does it?  I don't think it should, but appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Actually it solved the problem for us. But at the moment nothing works as repo.grails.org returns a "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable"